# Importing Text file with Null Character column separation

Tags: import, string-manipulation, named-characters

I have a text file (ANSI encoding) with two columns of real numbers separated, unfortunately, by a "*Null Character*" (`"\.00"`).

**How can I import this data easily?**

The problem:

```
Take[Import["17Dec15450K00.txt", "Table"], 3]
```

> ```
> {{"29.89128\.000.0119872"}, {"30.37339\.000.0120442"}, {"30.85551\.000.0123593"}}
> ```

But

```
ToExpression[Take[Import["17Dec15450K00.txt", "Table"], 3]]
```

> ```
> {{29.8913}, {30.3734}, {30.8555}}
> ```

Other functions also fail with if the string contains the Null Character

```
ToCharacterCode["999\.00999"]

StringReplace["999\.00999", "\.00" -> "X"]
```

Gives no output. **Is that a bug?**

File available [via Dropbox here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhj11nodvkzbfz6/17Dec15450K00.zip?dl=1)

UUE ZIP [via Pastebin here](https://pastebin.com/raw/U0VWp5zS)

Comment: I think this may be a bug but it's not that it gives no output - using `\.00` in a string gives an error.  See my related [Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102380/5414).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect to be robust you need to read in binary mode. Actually I would probably convert the nulls in one pass something like this:

```
in = OpenRead[file_with_nulls, BinaryFormat -> True] 
out = OpenWrite["tmp.out", BinaryFormat -> True] 
BinaryWrite[out, BinaryReadList[ in, "Byte"] /. 0 -> 32] (*32 -> space*)
Close /@ {in, out}
```

Then you should be able to use `Import`.

You could also use a command line tool like linux `tr` to repair the file.

This is totally untested as I don't have an example file to work with.

Answer (score 3):

I would not consider this an *EASY* solution, but it does the job.

```
file = OpenRead["17Dec15450K00.txt"];
data=Reap[
 While[
  Sow[
    Read[file, {Number, Byte, Number}]] =!= EndOfFile
  ]]
[[2, 1, ;; -2, {1, 3}]]
Close[file]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround:

```
ReadList["17Dec15450K00.txt", {Number, Byte, Number}][[All, {1, 3}]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why wouldn't you use this?

```
Import["17Dec15450K00.txt", "Data"]; // AbsoluteTiming
{0.187201, Null}
```

Import the text file as "Data" and no need to convert anything. I'm still using MMA 9

[image: Some how it works for me]

Comment: That actually does not work, you get a list of strings. and the NullCharacter makes it hard to parse.