# Entering NULL characters in a string

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, input-forms, named-characters, unicode

**Bug fixed in 12.3 or earlier**

---

This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102364/) is about parsing files that contain nulls (character code zero) as field separators.

Intending to attempt to answer this I began by trying to enter a string containing a null, e.g. by typing:

```
str = "123\.00456"
```

in the way that they are displayed in the linked question.  This is converted to `"123456"` as it is typed but evaluating it gives the following error [using *Mathematica* 10.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.11]:

> Syntax::tsntxi: "str=123\.00456" is incomplete; more input is needed.

So the null is being interpreted as a string termination character.  (But note that the message above is the result of copy & paste -- in the Front End it is displayed as `"str = 123456"`.)

Using the Unicode form `\:0000` gives the same error and I tried using `\[Null]` in my string but this has a character code different from zero (62368) so is not quite what I'm after.

I can generate the string using e.g.

```
(str = FromCharacterCode[{49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54}]) // FullForm
```

> "123\.00456"

**But is there any way of typing a string containing nulls directly, i.e. in a quoted string?**

Also should it be considered a bug that it is not possible to use the `FullForm` of a string containing a null as its `InputForm`?

Comment: Looks like a bug indeed since this input form is [well-documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CharacterCodes.html#24176).

Answer (score 7):

Turns out the answer is yes, simply use `"PrintableASCII"` character encoding rather than the `FullForm`/`InputForm` representation:

```
str = "123\000456"
ToCharacterCode[str]
```

> {49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54}

I discovered this using:

```
ToString[FromCharacterCode[{49, 50, 51, 0, 52, 53, 54}], InputForm, 
 CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"]
```

Which is basically from the [Special Characters and Strings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SpecialCharacters-StringsAndCharacters.html) tutorial in the Documentation.

So I am inclined to agree (with myself) that not being able to use the `\.00` or `\:0000` forms in a string is a bug.