# What does "\.00" in mathematica equal to?

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

When I type in:

```
"\.00"
```

in a notebook, the frontend automatically converts it to:

```
" "
```

on the screen it seems like there is only a white space. 
When I type a boolean query after the previous, but using the space bar to enter the white space:

```
" "== " "
```

Mathematica returns

> Syntax::tsntxi: ".00= " is incomplete; more input is needed.

What is the meaning of `\.00` in a string in Mathematica?

Comment: it should be ascii hex 00, which is`NUL` . I dont know the reason for that error.  I think this has been asked before but its pretty hard to search for

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102380/2079

Comment: `\.xx` is a way to specify a character by its code. The fact that this doesn't work in the front end feels like a bug ... In a terminal it works.  If you want a string with a null character in it, try `FromCharacterCode[{0}]` as a workaround.  If you want to type a `\ ` in a string, remember to escape it, `"\\"`.